# Checkbox is not checked on postback ASP NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, postback

I have a asp.net project where I have, lets call them objects. 
All objects are created in a repeater:

```
<section class="topbar">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_OnClick" Text="Save" />
</section>

<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="gwList">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="block">
            <input type="checkbox"  runat="server" ID="chkObjectSelected" value='<%# ((Object.Object)Container.DataItem).Id %>'/> 

            <label><%# ((Object.object)Container.DataItem).Title %></label>

        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here comes the problem, none of the selected objects will be set as selected in the postback. Here's the code i use to determine if the objects are checked:

```
protected void btnSave_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    List<string> objectIdSelected = new List<string>(); 

    foreach (RepeaterItem oneObject in gwList.Items)
    {
        HtmlInputCheckBox chkObj = (HtmlInputCheckBox)carAd.FindControl("chkObjectSelected");

        if (chkObj.Checked)
        {
            objectIdSelected.Add(chkObj.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you populate the Repeater in `Page_Load`? If so, make sure that it is inside an `if (!IsPostBack)` condition.

Comment: @ConnorsFan - This was the solution to my problem!

Answer (score 2):

try replacing

```
<input type="checkbox"  runat="server" ID="chkObjectSelected" value='<%# ((Object.Object)Container.DataItem).Id %>'/>
```

with this

```
 <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkObjectSelected" Value='<%# ((Object.Object)Container.DataItem).Id %>'/>
```

and change your code to this :

```
protected void btnSave_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> objectIdSelected = new List<string>();

    foreach (RepeaterItem oneObject in gwList.Items)
    {
        CheckBox chkObj = (CheckBox)oneObject.FindControl("chkObjectSelected");

        if (chkObj.Checked)
        {
            objectIdSelected.Add(chkObj.Attributes["Value"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This still does not work as expected. The value are added to the checkbox control, but it is never set as "checked". I get a feeling that somehow the repeateritem (the checkbox in this case) does not update the property of checked?

Comment: @Thugge are you using Update Panel?

Comment: No I am not using an Update Panel.

Answer (score 2):

Put an "`!Page.IsPostback`" condition around the logic in your Page_Load event.  What's probably happening is that your button causes a postback, and the page_load reloads your default (un-checked) value before the button click event fires.